# Tensorflow Estimator Hook access to features labels passed to model_fn and graph operations built during model_fn

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to understand a model built with the tensorflow Estimator framework. I'd like to use the Hooks API to add ops that process the input during evaluation, or prediction.

It seems I should be able to leave the `model_fn` used during training alone, and implement my own `SessionRunHook` class to add ops, but how do I get a hold of the input tensors for the model? For example, suppose `model_fn` looks like

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    concatanated_features = prepare_inputs(features, params)
    ...
```

and `prepare_inputs` just does something like

```
def prepare_inputs(features, params):
    return tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params['column_names'])`
```

Then I do something like

```
class MyHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    def begin(self):
        self.myTensor = my_function(features) # but how do I get features?
        self.myTensor2 = my_function(concatanated_features) # likewise,
        gr = tf.get_default_graph() # seems I have to start here and know what I'm looking for
```

Comment: I think I'm trying to do too much in a hook - I want to load a trained Estimator, so I wasn't going to touch the `model_fn` but I've since realized I can add ops to the graph in the model_fn I use to reload a trained estimator - I think as long as I dont add variables I can reload the trained weights from a checkpoint

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you looking at `TF Serve` for predictions. You can use the provided gRPC/REST API to call your saved model to get the prediction.

And, you can perform any required pre-processing before you generate the JSON request for REST call.
This example from TF covers `Serve`: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/serving/rest_simple?hl=en